# Importing 500 000 categories with Nested set Model with left and right.

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have 500 000 categories with below mysql table structure

CREATE TABLE nested_category (
        category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        lft INT NOT NULL,
        rgt INT NOT NULL
);

Here is how its following left and right http://mikehillyer.com/media//numbered_tree.png

I have another table from where i am getting row data has below structure.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_categories` (
`id` int(111) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(111) NOT NULL,
  `category_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `tdate` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=498013 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Which has data like this

```
id  category_id category_path               category_name   status  tdate
1   381773      Top/Arts                Arts        0   2014-10-07 11:11:05
2   423945      Top/Arts/Animation          Animation   0   2014-10-07 11:11:21
3   425085      Top/Arts/Animation/Anime        Anime       0   2014-10-07 11:11:34
4   425147      Top/Arts/Animation/Anime/Characters     Characters  0   2014-10-07 11:11:35
```

I have php script below to insert data

```
echo $sql = "Select * from tbl_categories where status='1' and`category_path` LIKE 'Top/Arts%' order by id limit 0,5";
$resCategory = select($sql);
for($k=0;$k<count($resCategory);$k++){

    $rec_id =$resCategory[$k]["id"];
    $category_id =$resCategory[$k]["category_id"];
    $category_path =$resCategory[$k]["category_path"];
    $category_name =$resCategory[$k]["category_name"];
    $friendly_url = getAlias($category_name);
    //exit;
    $cate_path_arr = explode("/",$category_path);
    $parent_full_friendly_url = "";
    $pad="";
    for($i=1;$i<count($cate_path_arr)-1;$i++){
        $parent_full_friendly_url .= $pad.getAlias($cate_path_arr[$i]);
        $pad="/";

    }

    $full_friendly_url = $parent_full_friendly_url.$pad.$friendly_url;

    if($cate_path_arr[count($cate_path_arr)-2]  == "Top"){
        $parent_category_id = 0;
    }else{
        $parentCatName  = $cate_path_arr[count($cate_path_arr)-2] ;     
        $sql = "Select id,root_id from nested_category where title = \"".$parentCatName."\" and full_friendly_url=\"".$parent_full_friendly_url."\"";
        $parentCat = select($sql);
        $parent_category_id = $parentCat[0]["id"];
        $root_id = $parentCat[0]["root_id"];

    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO nested_category SET ";
    $sql .= "root_id = \"".$root_id."\", ";
    $sql .= "title = \"".$category_name."\", ";
    $sql .= "category_id = \"".$parent_category_id."\", ";
    $sql .= "page_title = \"".$category_name."\", ";
    $sql .= "friendly_url = \"".$friendly_url."\", ";
    $sql .= "full_friendly_url = \"".$full_friendly_url."\", ";
    $sql .= "featured = \"y\", ";
    $sql .= "enabled = \"y\" ";
    $db->query($sql);
    $lastInsId = mysql_insert_id();


    $root_id = findRootCategoryId($lastInsId);

    if($parent_category_id > 0){
        $sql = "UPDATE nested_category SET count_sub = count_sub+1 where id=\"".$root_id."\"";
        $db->query($sql);
    }else{
        $sql = "UPDATE nested_category SET root_id = \"".$lastInsId."\" where id=\"".$lastInsId."\"";
        $db->query($sql);
    }

    rebuildCategoryTree($root_id, 1,$lastInsId);

    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_categories SET status = '0',tdate=\"".date("Y-m-d h:i:s")."\" where id=\"".$rec_id."\"";
    $db->query($sql);


}

function getAlias($catTitle){

    $alias = preg_replace("/(\s){2,}/",'$1',$catTitle);                 
    $alias = str_replace('-', '_', $alias);         
    $alias = preg_replace(array('/\s+/','/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/'), array('-','-'), $alias);           
    $page_alias = trim(strtolower($alias));

    return $page_alias;
}

function findRootCategoryId($category_id) {
            global $db,$dbSelect;
            $category_id = str_replace("'","",$category_id);
            while($category_id != 0) {
                $sql = "SELECT category_id, id FROM nested_category WHERE id = $category_id";               
                $row = select($sql);
                $category_id = $row[0]["category_id"];
                $root_category_id = $row[0]["id"];
            }
            return $root_category_id;
}


function rebuildCategoryTree($category_id, $node_left,$thisId) {
            global $db,$dbSelect;

            if (($category_id > 0) or ($thisId > 0)) {

                $category_id = ($category_id>0)?$category_id:$thisId;
                $node_left = ($node_left>0)?$node_left:1;
                $root_category_id = findRootCategoryId($category_id);

                $sql = 'UPDATE nested_category SET root_id = '.$root_category_id.' WHERE id='.$category_id;
                $db->query($sql);

                $node_right = $node_left+1;

                $sql = 'SELECT id FROM nested_category WHERE category_id= '.$category_id;
                $resParentCat = select($sql);

                for ($i=0;$i<count($resParentCat);$i++) {           
                    $node_right = rebuildCategoryTree($resParentCat[$i]['id'], $node_right,$thisId);
                }

                $sql = 'UPDATE nested_category SET `left` = '.$node_left.', `right` = '.$node_right.', root_id = '.$root_category_id.' WHERE  id = '.$category_id;
                $db->query($sql);



                return $node_right+1;

            }

        }
?>
```

My question is that is there any way that i can speed up the data insertion as its taking too much time to insert data by counting its left and right.

I know i have posted this question for the first time and i need you guys to give you all detail from my side. Please let me know your valuable comments.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should really change the way you store hierarchical data. Instead of left-right colums, you should use another approach called **Adjacency List Model** (where you only have `id` and `parent_id` columns)

Comment: @bad_boy thanks mate. Reason behind I am storing data is existing structure of website. I cant change that as I need to change a lot for that. Is there any better way of importing data fast other than above script?

Answer (score -1):

Don't let anyone yank your chain. For relatively stable data, Nested Set is far superior to Adjacency List. Here's a script I used to convert 800k+ rows of AL into NS. It typically ran in 6-8 minutes. It was originally written in T-SQL and I've made some changes to make it work (more or less) with your schema as you've shown it. It will need work to run in MySql. In any case, there is no need for functions or stored procedures. Everything you need can be plucked directly from the input table.

I've made two changes to your design. First, your sample data looks like it has a perfectly good identifying value so I used that instead of an Identity field. Second, I added the SetID column to maintain each set. So the finished data will look something like this:

```
id      SetID  Name        lft rgt
381773  Arts   Arts        0   11
423945  Arts   Animation   1   6
425085  Arts   Anime       2   5
425147  Arts   Character   3   4
132456  Arts   2D          7   10
123457  Arts   Painting    8   9
381773  Crafts Crafts      0   7
423945  Crafts Clay        1   6
425085  Crafts Structures  2   3
425147  Crafts Pottery     4   5
```

The entire table should not define one tree but rather a forest of trees (I call them "sets" in keeping with the "Nested Set" nomenclature) with the boundary numbering unique within each set. Each child of each set has the set identifier for grouping. Boundary numbering restarts at the beginning of each set so the left boundary value of each set root will be zero.

The code follows. Remember this is more a template than final code. Ask questions.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nested_category(
    ID      INT not null PRIMARY KEY,
    SetID   varchar( 20 ) not null,
    Name    VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    lft     INT NOT NULL,
    rgt     INT NOT NULL
);

-- This was originally written in T-SQL so some syntax modification will
-- be in order. Sorry.
declare
    @CatIDNew       int,
    @CatIDPrev      int = 0,
    @rgt            int,
    @SetID          varchar( 20 ),
    @NameNew        varchar( 20 ),
    @LevelNew       int,
    @LevelPrev      int = 0;

declare
    @Defs table(
        Lev     int,
        ID      int,
        Name    varchar( 20 ),
        lft     int
    );

declare SS cursor fast_forward for
    select  Category_ID, Category_Name, Length( Path ) - Length( Replace( Path, '/', '' )) as Category_Level
    from    tbl_categories
    --where   Category_Path like 'Top/Arts%' )  -- Uncomment to test a smaller sample
    order by Category_Path;

open ss;
fetch next from ss into @CatIDNew, @NameNew, @LevelNew;

-- Go ahead and store the first record of the table
insert into @Defs values( @LevelNew, @CatIDNew, @NameNew, 0 );
select  @LevelPrev  = @LevelNew,
        @CatIDPrev  = @CatIDNew,
        @SetID      = @NameNew,
        @rgt        = 1;
-- Get the second row
fetch next from ss into @CatIDNew, @NameNew, @LevelNew;

-- Now we enter the row with the first entry in the table variable. We're using this table as a stack.
-- As we read entries from the cursor, we push them "onto" the stack until we read an entry the same
-- or smaller level than the previous entry.
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
        if @LevelNew = 1 begin
            -- Handle the special case when transitioning between sets
            insert into nested_category( ID, SetID, Name, lft, rgt )
            select  ID, @SetID, Name, lft, @rgt +( @LevelPrev - Lev )
            from    @Defs
            where   Lev <= @LevelPrev
            order by Lev desc;

            -- Clear the stack
            delete @Defs;
            insert @Defs values( @LevelNew, @CatIDNew, @NameNew, 0 );

            select  @LevelPrev  = @LevelNew,
                    @CatIDPrev  = @CatIDNew,
                    @SetID      = @NameNew,
                    @rgt        = 1;
        end
        else if @LevelNew > @LevelPrev begin
            -- This new standard is the next level down from the last one. Save the last one.
            Merge into @Defs d
                using (select @LevelNew) as Search( Lev )
                    on d.Lev = Search.Lev
                when matched then
                    update  set ID      = @CatIDNew,
                                Name    = @NameNew,
                                lft     = @rgt
                when not matched then
                    insert values( @LevelNew, @CatIDNew, @NameNew, @rgt );
            select  @LevelPrev  = @LevelNew,
                    @rgt     = @rgt + 1;
        end
        else begin
            -- This is on the same or higher level as the last one. We can write out the last one to the new level.
            insert into nested_category( ID, SetID, Name, lft, rgt )
            select  ID, @SetID, Name, lft, @rgt +( @LevelPrev - Lev )
            from    @Defs
            where   Lev between @LevelNew and @LevelPrev;
            -- Then insert/replace the new one (in case the next one is lower)
            select  @LevelPrev  = @LevelNew,
                    @CatIDPrev  = @CatIDNew,
                    @rgt = @rgt + @@ROWCOUNT;
            Merge into @Defs d
                using (select @LevelNew) as Search( Lev )
                    on d.Lev = Search.Lev
                when matched then
                    update  set ID      = @NameNew,
                                Name    = @NameNew,
                                lft     = @rgt
                when not matched then
                    insert values( @LevelNew, @CatIDNew, @NameNew, @rgt );
            set @rgt = @rgt + 1;
        end;

    -- Read in the next row
    fetch next from ss into @CatIDNew, @NameNew, @LevelNew;
end;

-- There are no more entries. Purge any remaining in the stack.
insert into nested_category( ID, SetID, Name, lft, rgt )
select  ID, @SetID, Name, lft, @rgt +( @LevelPrev - Lev )
from    @Defs
where   Lev <= @LevelPrev;

close ss;
deallocate ss;

-- Saving these definitions until after the table is loaded saves a lot of time.
alter table nested_category add
    constraint  PK_nested_category primary key clustered( ID ),
    constraint  IX_nested_category_lft unique( SetID, lft ),
    constraint  CK_nested_categoryBounds check( lft < rgt );
alter table nested_category add
    constraint  FK_nested_categoryOrgID foreign key( SetID )references StandardOrgs( SetID ),
    constraint  FK_nested_categoryGUID foreign key( ID )references StandardGuidXref ( EDID ),
    constraint  FK_nested_categorySubject foreign key( SubjectID )references StandardSubjects ( ID ),
    constraint  FK_nested_categoryLevel foreign key( SetID, LevelID )references StandardLevels ( SetID, LevelID );
create index    IX_nested_categoryBounds on nested_category ( SetID, lft, rgt ); -- oft-used covering index
```

Comment: :While its true insertion is expensive. Maybe try closures or material paths?

Comment: Do you mean closure tables or materialized paths? If you have a different answer, then by all means, provide it. Don't just drop a couple of mangled buzzwords and disappear.

Comment: :No thanks,I wrote "try" and I mean also AL model. So three more options not just closures or materialzes path. BTW. I don't what closure is. Maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: The OP was not asking for suggestions for storing hierarchical data. He already has that. He was just asking if there was a faster way to import from one form into the form he already had. Having done just that several times in the past, I made my suggestion.

Comment: Btw, if you don't know what a closure (table) is, why did you even suggest it in the first place? But, to answer *your* question, take a look at http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html, which is pretty good. But there is lots more if you don't mind a little digging around. For a fairly exhaustive list of the entire subject (storing hierarchical data in a relational database), try http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/links/#hierarchical.